# Смена курсора в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Как в WPF проекте можно изменить курсор мыши на свой, подгруженный в ресурсах проекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понятие «ресурса» в .NET достаточно размыто: есть linked resources, embedded resources, а также ресурсы, доступные через свойства проекта → Resources.

Например, для случая linked resources (это когда вы добавляете файл в проект, и устанавливаете Build Action = Resource (не Embedded Resource!)), подойдёт следующий код для загрузки курсора:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Res/my.cur");
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
var cursor = new Cursor(stream);
```

в окне установите

```
Cursor = cursor;
```